# I would like to identify a specific part of Ibn Khaldun's Muqaddimah

Tags: translation, arabic-language, ibn-khaldun, muqaddimah

I would like to identify the passage from the Arabic original text of Ibn Khaldun's Muqaddimah whose translation is the following one. It corresponds to Chapter 38 of Book 6, and the quoted translation is [this one](http://www.muslimphilosophy.com/ik/Muqaddimah/), with emphasis added.

> 38. The instruction of children and the different methods employed in the Muslim cities.
>
> It should be known that instructing children in the Qur'an is a symbol of Islam. Muslims have, and practice, such instruction in all their cities, because it imbues hearts with a firm belief (in Islam) and its articles of faith, which are (derived) from the verses of the Qur'an and certain Prophetic traditions. The Qur'an has become the basis of instruction, the foundation for all habits that may be acquired later on. **The reason for this is that the things one is taught in one's youth take root more deeply (than anything else). They are the basis of all later (knowledge). The first impression the heart receives is, in a way, the foundation of (all scholarly) habits. The character of the foundation determines the condition of the building.** The methods of instructing children in the Qur'an differ according to differences of opinion as to the habits that are to result from that instruction.

However, I am only a beginner in Arabic and I cannot find it. Could any Arabic speaker show me where the equivalent original Arabic text is, e.g. in [this edition of the text](https://archive.org/details/muqaddimatalalla008800/)?

Comment: Are you using an actual book or online source only? I see some typographical/formatting issue in your block quote.

Answer (score 3):

The chapters' numbers are not consistent between the English and Arabic editions that you linked to. In the Arabic edition, the text is actually found in chapter 31. Following the actual numbering of the paper book, you can find it on page #537 (page #541 if you follow the numbering of the e-book).

Here's a [direct link](https://archive.org/details/muqaddimatalalla008800/page/n540/mode/2up), and here's the original (Arabic) of the quoted text:

> الفصل الواحد والثلاثون
>
> في تعليم الولدان واختلاف مذاهب الأمصار الإسلامية في طرقه
>
> اعلم أن تعليم الولدان للقرآن شعارُ الدين. أخذ به أهل الملة ودرجوا عليه في جميع أمصارهم لما يسبق فيه إلى القلوب من رسوخ الإيمان وعقائده من آيات القرآن وبعض متون الأحاديث. وصار القرآن  أصل التعليم الذي ينبني عليه ما يحصل بعد من الملكات. **وسبب ذلك أن التعليم في الصغر أشد رسوخاً، وهو أصلٌ لما بعده لأن السابق الأول للقلوب كالأساس للملكات. وعلى حسب الأساس وأساليبه يكون حال من ينبني عليه.** واختلفت طرقهم في تعليم القرآن للوِلدان باختلافهم باعتبار ما ينشأ عن ذلك التعليم من الملكات.